# Históricamente, ¿cómo se ha definido en los diccionarios el "metro" como unidad de medida?

Tags: definiciones, historia, ciencia

La definición actual del metro como unidad de medida en el DRAE es la siguiente:

> **[metro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P8Tr0Ih)**
>
> 1. m. Unidad de longitud del sistema internacional, que originalmente se estableció como la diezmillonésima (10<sup>−7</sup>) parte del cuadrante del meridiano terrestre, y hoy, con más precisión, se define como la longitud del trayecto recorrido en el vacío por la luz durante un tiempo de 1/299 792 458 de segundo. (Símb. m).

Esta definición parece ser demasiado moderna como para que se registrara así en los diccionarios anteriores. Históricamente, ¿cómo se ha ido definiendo el metro como unidad de medida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La primera aparición del metro como unidad de medida fue en el de la Real Academia de 1852, cuando el metro era aún una extraña unidad de medida del país vecino:

> FRANCÉS. Medida de esta nacion, que es la base de todas las suyas. Se usa tambien en otras naciones.

Al año siguiente, en 1853, el *Diccionario Nacional* de Ramón Joaquín Domínguez aclara:

> Unidad de medida longitudinal en el nuevo sistema métrico decimal, que se usa en Francia; equivale á una diezmillonésima parte del arco de meridiano terrestre, comprendido entre el polo boreal y el ecuador.

Esta definición se mantuvo en los siguientes diccionarios. En 1869, la RAE añade un poco más de información añadiendo una conversión:

> Equivale á poco más de tres piés y medio castellanos.

Información que el suplemento del diccionario de Domínguez precisaba en:

> 3,5889216 pies castellanos.

En 1884 la RAE cambia la conversión pero mantiene la inexactitud:

> Equivale á poco más de 43 pulgadas castellanas.

Los siguientes diccionarios mantienen esta última conversión, que la RAE actualiza en 1899 añadiendo por fin algo más de precisión:

> [...] equivale á unas 43 pulgadas castellanas, ó sea 3 pies y 59 centésimas.

En 1914 se dan cuenta de que la definición seguía siendo inexacta, y por fin añaden:

> [...] calculada para el cuadrante de meridiano que pasa por París [...]

Así ya por fin aclaran que no todos los meridianos sirven. Esta definición se mantiene hasta el diccionario de 1970 incluido. Ya en 1984 deciden que eso de realizar la conversión usando pies y pulgadas está ya más que obsoleto, y la cambian por:

> En los países adheridos a la convención del metro, tiene valor legal una definición en la que se fija la longitud de este en función de la longitud de onda de determinada raya espectral del criptón.

Seguimos con las inexactitudes ("determinada raya espectral"), pero al menos ya se meten en terreno más científico. Tal vez consideraron que demasiado, porque en 1992 quitaron eso del criptón que quedaba demasiado técnico, y lo dejan en:

> [...] la cual se determinó dividiendo en diez millones de partes iguales la longitud calculada para el cuadrante de meridiano que pasa por París.

Punto. Ya por fin en 2001 se define el metro usando la misma definición que tiene hoy día, basada en la distancia recorrida por la luz.